# How to put data on the right side of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a little Task list application using Xcode 7 and Swift. However, I want some of the data, such as the date label, to be on the right side of the UITableViewCell, except for the left. What code would I use to put the date label on the right side of a UITableViewCell?

Here is my code for my ViewController.swift, that has the TableView.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

// All Outlets Connected to StoryBoard
@IBOutlet var BTN: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var BTN2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var BTN3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var BTN4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tbl: UITableView?
@IBOutlet var Button: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var Bar: UINavigationItem!

//Other Variables
var varView = Int()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.\





    if revealViewController() != nil {

        Button.target = revealViewController()
        Button.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

    }


    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 50 / 255.0, green: 132 / 255.0, blue: 255 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)




    BTN.alpha = 1.0
    BTN4.alpha = 0


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func BTNClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: ({


        self.BTN2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -90)
        self.BTN3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -180)
        self.BTN4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        self.BTN.alpha = 0
        self.BTN4.alpha = 1.0



    }))
}


@IBAction func BTNClickedAgain(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: ({


        self.BTN2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        self.BTN3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        self.BTN4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        self.BTN.alpha = 1.0
        self.BTN4.alpha = 0



    }))
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        taskMgr.tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tbl?.reloadData();
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tbl?.reloadData();
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return taskMgr.tasks.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")

        cell.textLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].date
        return cell
}
```

Also, here is a look at my AddPlan.swift, this is where I add the Data to the UITableViewCells in the ViewControlelr.swift:

```
class addPlan: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


var time: Int = 6


@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var txt2: UITextField! // This is the data text, I want this to be on the left side of the UITableViewCell.
@IBOutlet var txt1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Button02: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addPlan.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.txt.delegate = self;
    self.txt1.delegate = self;
    self.txt2.delegate = self;




    if revealViewController() != nil {

        Button02.target = revealViewController()
        Button02.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

    }


}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}


@IBAction func ClickedforSelection(sender: UIButton) {
    taskMgr.addTask(txt.text!, desc: txt1.text!, date: txt2.text!)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    txt.text = ""
    txt1.text = ""
    txt2.text = "" // This is the data text


}
}
```

Comment: If you want a specific design of a table view cell you need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and design the cell in IB. It is very simple to do and there are a large number of tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `UITableViewCellStyle.Value1` or `UITableViewCellStyle.Value2` for your UITableViewCell style.

from [Table View Styles and Accessory Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1)

> `UITableViewCellStyle.Value1` puts the subtitle in blue text and
>   right-aligns it on the right side of the row. Images are not
>   permitted.
>
> While `UITableViewCellStyle.Value2` puts the main title in blue and
>   right-aligns it at a point that’s indented from the left side of the
>   row. The subtitle is left aligned at a short distance to the right of
>   this point. This style does not allow images.

Comment: Yeah I was looking it over. Is it possible to use Subtitle and Value2 at the same time? That is actually my real question.

Comment: it is possible if you create your custom `UITableViewCell`.